# Python : Socket Sending Struct(having C stuct as Example)

Tags: python, c, sockets, struct, python-3.x

**Below Are Struct from C,and i m trying Convert to Python,
and use Socket to sending out the struct**

C:

```
        struct CommandReq
        {
            char    sMark[6];  //start flag\r\n*KW
            short   nPackLen;  //packet length
            short   nFlag;     //command ID 0x0002
            int     nGisIp;    //GIS port
            short   nPort;     //GIS Port
            char    sData[50]; //command string
            char    sEnd[2];   //end flag "\r\n"
        };
        //source code
        CommandReq stResq;
        memset(&stResq, 0, sizeof(stResq));
        sprintf(stResq.sMark, "\r\n%s", "*KW");
        stResq.nFlag = 0x0002;
        stResq.nPackLen = sizeof(stResq);
        stResq.nGisIp = 0;
        stResq.nPort = 0;
        strcpy(stResq.sData, "*KW,CC09C00001,015,080756,#");
        strncpy(stResq.sEnd, "\r\n", 2);
```

I have created Python struct using namedtuple,and use socket to send this struct.
but unfortunately failed.

Python:

```
from collections import namedtuple
MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "sMark nPackLen nFlag nGisIp nPort sData sEnd")
```

## Edit, in reply to answer below

after figure out, python 3.x must be added string .encode("ascii")

```
      format_ = "6shhih50s2s"
      MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "sMark nPackLen nFlag nGisIp nPort sData sEnd")
      tuple_to_send = MyStruct(sMark="\r\n{}".format("*KW").encode("ascii"), 
                 nPackLen=struct.calcsize(format_),
                 nFlag=0x0002,
                 nGisIp=0,
                 nPort=0,
                 sData= "*KW,NR09G05133,015,080756,#".encode("ascii"),
                 sEnd="\r\n".encode("ascii"))
      string_to_send = struct.pack(format_, *tuple_to_send._asdict().values()
      socket.sendto(string_to_send, self.client_address)
```

### Additional Question

below is the packet are sending out with the struct

```
format_ = "6shhih50s2s" //total bytes should be 68 bytes?
    0d0a2a4b5700 //6 char \r\n*KW
    4600 // packet length 70 bytes
    0200 //command ID 0x0002,short 2 bytes
    00000000 //GIS port is integer 4 bytes
    0000 //GIS Port short 2 bytes
    0000 //unknown??what is this?
    2a4b572c4e5230394730353133332c3031352c3038303735362c230000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 //sData[50] char 50 bytes
    0d0a //sEnd 2 char,2 bytes
```

how come the 2 unknown bytes??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

namedtuple isn't really comparable to a c-struct. If you are used to using structs, you can have a look at the [`struct`-module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to convert structured information to a string.

In general, Pythonistas prefer using the [`pickle`-module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) for serialization.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pickle # or cPickle, it's faster
MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "sMark nPackLen nFlag nGisIp nPort sData sEnd")

tuple_to_send = MyStruct(sMark="abcdef", nPackLen=...)
string_to_send = pickle.dumps(tuple_to_send)
```

There are two flavors of pickle, `pickle` and `cPickle`. The latter is faster, but is only available in CPython (which most programmers use), while pickle is also available in Jython, IronPython, ...

If you want to stick to struct (e.g., because the other side expects this format), your format string will be

```
format_ = "6shhih50s2s"
```

So you can do:

```
import struct
from collections import namedtuple

format_ = "6shhih50s2s"

MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "sMark nPackLen nFlag nGisIp nPort sData sEnd")
tuple_to_send = MyStruct(sMark="\r\n{}".format("*KW"), 
                     nPackLen=struct.calcsize(format_),
                     nFlag=0x0002,
                     nGisIp=0,
                     nPort=0,
                     sData= "*KW,NR09G05133,015,080756,#",
                     sEnd="\r\n")


string_to_send = struct.pack(format_, *tuple_to_send._asdict().values())
```

BTW: namedtuples are immutable, i.e., you cannot do

```
tuple_to_send.sMark = "bcdefg"
```

to change some property. If you need such behavior, you must create a class.

**Edit**

For Python 3, string-treatment has changed. Conversion from unicode to bytes has to be performed, e.g.

```
import struct
from collections import namedtuple

format_ = "6shhih50s2s"

MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "sMark nPackLen nFlag nGisIp nPort sData sEnd")
tuple_to_send = MyStruct(sMark="\r\n{}".format("*KW").encode("ascii"), 
                     nPackLen=struct.calcsize(format_),
                     nFlag=0x0002,
                     nGisIp=0,
                     nPort=0,
                     sData= "*KW,NR09G05133,015,080756,#".encode("ascii"),
                     sEnd=b"\r\n")


string_to_send = struct.pack(format_, *tuple_to_send._asdict().values())
```

Comment: sData are 50 chac?how to do on this 50?

Comment: Look at [this table](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters). Here, all format specifications for the struct-module are explained. Does this help?

Comment: @Thorsen Kranz , No,it doesn't help.
how to declare chac[50] in a namedtuple?or somewhere?

Comment: Python doesn't know about char-arrays. I'll prepare an example of using `struct`.

Comment: Thanks,i m waiting for it @Thorsten Kranz

Comment: if sending without declare Char[50] , the bytes size sending out is different already.the Client Side will ignore this packet. @Thorsten Kranz have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I declare a char[50] by using `50s` in my `format_`-string. This will make sure the resulting `string_to_send` will reserve exactly this size for `sData`, evene if the string you put in is shorter.

Comment: what is the value on the nPackLen?in C is sizeof(struct)

Comment: see the documentation: [struct.calcsize(format_)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.calcsize)

Comment: struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object //on struct.pack there

Comment: What do you put into your namedtuple? What does `print [type(x) for x in tuple_to_send._asdict().values()]` print?

Comment: I've updated my answer to take the same values. It works for me without any problem.

Comment: is that any different i m using Python 3.X?

Comment: [<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>] //this is what i printed with the tuple_to_send._asdict().values()

Comment: With Python 3, string treatments has changed. You try to put unicode-strings in where byte-strings are expected. I'd suggest putting a `.encode("ascii")` after every string for the struct - though I don't know if that is what you want. Probably, you should make sure your data are bytes from the beginnning.

Comment: don't know why client Side Didn't reply the bytes string,when server send a command to client, client side should reply success or failed,even failed also have sending the error code,still finding the problem..

Comment: i have use wireshark to capture the packet sending out, all the packet size is 70 bytes,is that correct?

Comment: i realize that total all bytes only 68bytes, how come i m sending the 70 Bytes to the client?i have edited the question,please see it.

Comment: i have discovery python format_ = "6shhih50s2s"(i = integer) are 6 bytes?!? impossible @Thorsten Kranz

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23879/discussion-between-thorsten-kranz-and-anthor)