# What is the appropriate way to flatten or serialize data in Python so it only contains the data bytes byes?

Tags: python, serialization, flatten

I'm a heavy LabVIEW user who is just starting to learn Python. I work with industrial and aerospace equipment a lot and something I need to do very often is process some data, then export it over some communications protocol in binary. For example, let's say I have a packet that contains a struct/cluster/other-complex-data-element that has the following underlying data elements:

sync - unsigned 32-bit integer
time - 64-bit double
payload ID - 16-bit signed integer
source - 16-but signed integer
destination - 16-bit signed integer
payload length - 32 bit signed integer
data 1 - 8-bit unsigned integer
data 2 - 8-bit unsigned integer
data 3 - 8-bit unsigned integer
data 4 - 8-bit unsigned integer
data 4 - 64-bit double
data 5 - 32-bit single
data 6 - 16 bit unsigned integer
crc - 32-bit unsigned integer

(This frame should be 42 bytes long)

I call this a frame, where there is some header information, a payload, then a crc, I think that's a common term for what I'm creating. The data types, and their location in the byte stream is critical. Any extraneous or missing bytes breaks the data transfer protocol and the data cannot be tolerated.

My question is this:

How do you achieve this easily in Python? In LabVIEW (and probably other languages), there are good, built in functions and methods to clearly define the data types, then flatten them to a string of bytes that is very efficient. It seems that with picking, there are things going on that I don't understand.

In my example code, I have a simple function to get some memory information, then serialize it. I would expect the integer version to have 88 bytes and the float version to have 172 bytes, but I get 87 and 115 respectively. Here is the code, thanks for your help!

```
import psutil
import time
import pickle

def getMemoryInfo():

    while True:
        virtual_memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
        swap_memory = psutil.swap_memory()
        memoryInfo = list(virtual_memory+swap_memory)
        # memoryInfo = [float(x) for x in memoryInfo]
        time.sleep(1.000)
        print(memoryInfo)
        string = pickle.dumps(memoryInfo)
        print(string)
        print(len(memoryInfo))
        print(len(string))

getMemoryInfo()
```

Comment: Probably need more inf: what do `print(virtual_memory)` and `print(swap_memory)` display?

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Did you try to use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module?

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? [Python : Socket Sending Struct(having C stuct as Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620632/python-socket-sending-structhaving-c-stuct-as-example), [Serializing a C struct in Python and sending over a socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533409/serializing-a-c-struct-in-python-and-sending-over-a-socket)..

Comment: The struct module did it, thanks! It was a little more tedious than I would have hoped, but it did exactly what I needed, thanks! Here's the code I ended up using:

Answer (score 0):

The struct module worked for me. It was a little more tedious than I would have hoped, but it worked just fine. Here is the code I ended up using:

def build_frame(payload, payload_class, payload_id, source, destination):

```
# form frame header and payload
frame = {"sync": int(0x64617665),
         "absolute_time": time.time(),
         "relative_time": time.monotonic(),
         "source": int(source),
         "destination": int(destination),
         "counter": 0,
         "payload_class": int(payload_class),
         "payload_id": int(payload_id),
         "payload_length": int(len(payload)),
         "payload": payload}

# form bytearray to crc
sync = (struct.pack('<I', frame['sync']))
absolute_time = (struct.pack('<d', frame['absolute_time']))
relative_time = (struct.pack('<d', frame['relative_time']))
source = (struct.pack('i', frame['source']))
destination = (struct.pack('i', frame['destination']))
counter = (struct.pack('I', frame['counter']))
payload_class = (struct.pack('i', frame['payload_class']))
payload_id = (struct.pack('i', frame['payload_id']))
payload_length = (struct.pack('i', frame['payload_length']))
payload_bytes = frame['payload']
crc_bytes = sync + absolute_time + relative_time + source + destination + counter + payload_class + payload_id + payload_length + payload_bytes

# crc bytes and add to frame
frame['crc'] = binascii.crc32(crc_bytes)

return frame
```